# Error while join table in SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have two tables that have relationship with `UserName` field. Based on `UserName` column, I want to get `ID` from `CarReserve` table. Here is my SQL statement:

```
SELECT CarReserve.ID 
FROM CarReserve 
 INNER JOIN aspnet_Users ON CarReserve.UserName = aspnet_Users.UserName 
WHERE UserName = @UserName
```

Unfortunately, I am getting this warning:

> Ambiguous column name "UserName"

Can anyone here tell me what is wrong with my statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add table name before `UserName` in `WHERE UserName = @UserName`

Your query should be:

```
SELECT CarReserve.ID 
    FROM CarReserve 
    INNER JOIN aspnet_Users ON CarReserve.UserName = aspnet_Users.UserName 
    WHERE aspnet_Users.UserName = @UserName
    ------^-----------^----------------
```

Or

```
SELECT CarReserve.ID 
    FROM CarReserve 
    INNER JOIN aspnet_Users ON CarReserve.UserName = aspnet_Users.UserName 
    WHERE CarReserve.UserName = @UserName
    ------^---------^----------------
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add aspnet_users. before the username in your where clause.

I may suggest using aliases for your tables too.

Answer (score 1):

You have to alias the `username` field in the `WHERE` clause to be unambiguously qualified:

```
SELECT CarReserve.ID 
FROM CarReserve 
INNER JOIN aspnet_Users ON CarReserve.UserName = aspnet_Users.UserName 
WHERE aspnet_Users.UserName = @UserName
```